# My hidden file input fields extends mysteriously on the left side

Tags: html, css, file-io

I am hiding my file input button by the following css

```
.picture-link {
    height: 2px;
    width: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.picture-link > input{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)
}
```

my html

```
<span class="picture-link update-box-icon-link"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                                              <input type="file" name="upd-img-file" class="upd-img-file" data-url="/post/image/upload" multiple/>
                                           </span>
```

I see the button somehow extends to some mysterious portion as shown in the picture.It is only happening in the left side.
The input field is hidden under the camera icon.Any clue?

[image]

Comment: using an inline element as parent for other elemnts always brings some mysterious happenings, why do you do that?=

Comment: add to the css picture-link { ... display:block; or inline-block
or use another element then span